# Button state drawable pressed triggering multiple buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-drawable, material-components-android

Have some buttons with their background set to the drawable custom_button.xml. The selector is suppose to change the drawable when pressed, disabled, and default. For some reason when I press any button in the view the last button in my layout will also have its drawable set to rounded_corner_pressed. This is all done through the selector. I've tried adding state_focus to no avail. Any ideas?

**EDIT** Tried to make the question more clear

custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true" f
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_disabled" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" />
</selector>
```

rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/background_color" />
    <padding android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

---

rounded_corner_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/background_color" />
    <padding android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

---

Layout It's in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="85dp"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/questionView"
        android:text="Answer 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerOne"
        android:text="Answer 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerThree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerTwo"
        android:text="Answer 3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerFour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerThree"
        android:text="Answer 4" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/retrievingProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can semplify your layout.
For your buttons just use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:text="BUTTON"
    app:cornerRadius="8dp"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/myColor"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/myselector"
    ../>
```

[image]

For the TextView you can use a [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md).

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:text="Text"
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
onlick{
lastbuttonName.performClick();
}
```

Comment: i have tried to understand your question what i understood that you want to trigger last button with first button click.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the answer, I am not happy with it but it did fix the problem. After I click one of the buttons I change the background to an incorrect drawable (similar to rounded corner just different background color) for a few seconds then set it back like so.

```
Drawable defaultDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.custom_button);
answerOne.setBackground(defaultDrawable);
answerTwo.setBackground(defaultDrawable);
answerThree.setBackground(defaultDrawable);
answerFour.setBackground(defaultDrawable);
```

This must cause a reference issue because now whenever I click buttons 1, 2, or 3 then the state is changed for button 4 for as well. To fix this I just hacked it and added a unique drawable to each button like so.

```
Drawable defaultDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.custom_button);
Drawable defaultDrawable1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.custom_button);
Drawable defaultDrawable2 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.custom_button);
Drawable defaultDrawable3 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.custom_button);
answerOne.setBackground(defaultDrawable);
answerTwo.setBackground(defaultDrawable1);
answerThree.setBackground(defaultDrawable2);
answerFour.setBackground(defaultDrawable3);
```